# HyperLink on textview without url not shown and not clickable

Tags: android, hyperlink, android-alertdialog

I want to show hyperLinke on textview but not on url, For Example: Hi How are "url".(here url will open www.google.com). And all those will be on Alert Dialog..

I have followed following approche but didn't get the proper solution..

String.xml---
<a href=http://www.google.co.in>Google</a>

```
        String str = getResources().getString(R.string.link);
        final TextView txtvw = new TextView(this);
        txtvw.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
        txtvw.setClickable(true);
        txtvw.setAutoLinkMask(RESULT_OK);
        txtvw.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        Linkify.addLinks(txtvw, Linkify.WEB_URLS);

        AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alt_bld.setTitle(title);

        alt_bld.setCancelable(false);

        alt_bld.create();
        alt_bld.setView(txtvw).show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CDATA tag:

```
<string name="link"><![CDATA[ <a href="http://www.google.co.in">Google</a> ]]></string>
```

UPDATE:

```
String str = getResources().getString(R.string.link);
final TextView txtvw = new TextView(this);
txtvw.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
txtvw.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setView(txtvw)
                .show();
```

Comment: I tries it but didn't work...same behavior showing Google but not as as hyperlink as well as not clickable...

Comment: Ive checked both codes - first doesnt work but mine is working.Are you sure? Did you cut off all unnecessary code? Try to set `String str = " <a href="http://www.google.co.in">Google</a>";` explicitly instead of using resources and tell me if it work

Comment: Hey Pleerock... Thanks man...It works after commenting all other lines and with the use of CDATA tag...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure. But this could be because you missed double quotes on your href,

Give this format a try,

```
<a href="http://www.google.co.in">Google</a>
```

Comment: so what kind of output are you getting then? can u explain?

Comment: It can be because you are trying to add your TextView as a View to alert dialog. Did u check it by having the TextView in Activity screen instead of alert dialog. so that you can see if you code works and do some alternative work to make it work on a alert?